# Wrong validations messages are triggered when validating input text field knockout validation plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am researching the knockout validator plugin. I have an input text control in the view:

```
Prefix:
<input data-bind = "value: Prefix" />
```

I am doing some validation on the Prefix observable variable:

```
Prefix.extend({
            minLength: 3,
            required: true
        });
```

The validation is working but when I enter one character in the input text box and change the focus the message for required rule is shown, not that for minLength. I tried some alternative syntax:

```
Prefix.extend({ required: true })
            .extend({ minLength: 3 })
```

But nothing changes. If I enter the minimum required characters and then delete them one by one, the correct rule messages are triggered (minLength message and required message when no characters are left). I am not very much familiar with javascript and I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: EDIT: This issue is reported here :

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues/47

According to the author its fixed, but I can still reproduce it in my code. Maybe I should write there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version of knockout you're using. I ran into this issue and found that I was using knockout 2.0.0, the newest version (2.1.0) seems to fix this issue.

Comment: I switched to jquery validation plugin but I tried the knockout validation plugin after your post with 2.1.0 version of knockout. You are right. I cannot reproduce the bug any more. Thank You for your answer!